# Maximum number of associated records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'd like to have a maximum number of associated records on a model.
E.g. a project has_many tasks, but not more then twenty.

How can I enforce this rule?

The only solution that I've been able to come up with so far is an
`INSERT INTO...SELECT` query like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  tasks (`id`,`project_id`,`title`,`body`)
SELECT
  NULL, ?, ?, ?
FROM
  tasks
HAVING
  count(id) < MAX_NUMBER_OF_TASKS
LIMIT 1;
```

1. As far as I can tell, this will guarantee a maximum number of tasks being inserted. Am I correct in this?
2. Is there a 'Rails way' to do this?
3. Is it possible to override ActiveRecord/the Task model so that it uses the query above
   to insert a new record?

I'm currently using a custom method with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`
and calling that instead of `.create` or `.save` when `new_record? == true`.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to try this, but I can't see why it shouldn't work.

Step one: Define a validator on the parent object (this is a simple implementation - could/should be made more generic):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :max_tasks

  def max_tasks
    if tasks.count > 20
      errors.add_to_base("Should not have more than 20 tasks")
    end
  end
end
```

Step two: Turn on validation of project from tasks:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_associated :project
end
```

And I think you should be in business. When you try and save a new task, it'll validate the associated project, and the validation will fail if there are (now) more than 20 tasks associated.

Just in case you fancy making this more generic, you could do something like:

```
class NumberOfAssociatedValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if options[:maximum] && record.send(attribute).count > options[:maximum]
      record.errors[attribute] << "must not have more than #{options[:maximum]}"
    end
    if options[:minimum] && record.send(attribute).count < options[:minimum]
      record.errors[attribute] << "must not have less than #{options[:minimum]}"
    end
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :my_association, :number_of_associated => {:maxiumum => 20}
end
```

Comment: Validation on the application level can't guarantee that there won't be 21 tasks. If two tasks would be submitted simultaneously (and processed by a different instances/server) it's possible that they both see `tasks.count > 20 == false` and therefore insert the record.

Comment: Is that true even if carried out in a transaction with isolation levels set appropriately? Should cause the section transaction to abort? Fair challenge though.

Comment: Yep. See [validates_uniqueness_of does not guarantee uniqueness](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2008/09/20/validates_uniqueness_of-does-not-guarantee-uniqueness/) for example where it says it "could even happen if you use transactions with the 'serializable' isolation level". Different use case, same principle.

Comment: TBH I'm struggling to buy that, as I don't see how that can be true without the database violating the isolation level rules. A bit of googling reveals people suggesting this /does/ work, and others suggesting it doesn't, but always without much explanation. Sounds like a confused picture :( Have you tried it properly?

Comment: A simple `SELECT` doesn't block. You could start a transaction, do a select, see that there are 19 tasks and insert a new one. In the time between selecting and inserting another transaction could have inserted as well, leaving you with 21 tasks. Another solution I think would be to do a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` on the appropriate fields which does block other transactions from reading the task count for a project.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can add some pre save validation to your model, that checks how many associated models it already have, and throw a validation error if it exceeds your max number of associations.

Comment: That would be inherently prone to race conditions afaik. See [validates_uniqueness_of does not guarantee uniqueness](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2008/09/20/validates_uniqueness_of-does-not-guarantee-uniqueness/) for example.